# Macbook Pro Mid-2012, ethernet heating

Tags: macbook-pro, ethernet, temperature

I am a Mac newbie and I have a new 13" Macbook Pro.

I used the Ethernet connection for wired Internet in my dorm room, but after using it for half an hour or so, the Ethernet port and the area nearby started heating up. After it got considerably hot, I unplugged the Ethernet cable. The cable is CAT5e (not CAT6 for gigabit ethernet) and a rather cheap one and I sincerely hope that this is the reason for the heating problem. Is it so? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did unplugging the ethernet resolve the problem? You can't isolate causality without testing the heat (under the same conditions i.e. same apps in use) with the ethernet unplugged. More than likely that is just normal processor heat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unplugging resolved the problem. It was kinda high for a normal processor heat, that's why I'm concerned.

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: Have you tried the usual SMC/PRAM reset?

Comment: Hello, sorry to reply late. I bought a Belkin brand CAT6 ethernet cable. There still is some heating after an hour of connection, but it is in the normal range. The problem seems to be solved; but if excessive heating strikes again, I will look into the SMC/PRAM resetting as you suggested. Thank you very much for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you were doing on the Mac. For instance, if you were doing a lot photo editing the heat build up in that area is normal. This is where the power adapter plugs in and the internal heat-sink is located. The more power processor needed the hotter that area becomes. Not to worry though, the built cooling system in the Mac will take care of the heat buildup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just using Safari, nothing more and it built up heat constantly. The power adapter was also connected, maybe that was the reason, ethernet and power hubs are just too close to each other. But not having Mac connected to adapter while using the ethernet is kind of a limitation.